# JSON url field is not correctly displaying

Tags: php, json

So this is where to view my json file: http://alyssayango.x10.mx/

this is my php file for that:

```
  <?php
include('connectdb.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmovies ORDER BY _id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
if($result === FALSE) {
 die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
$set = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $set[] = $row1;
}
echo json_encode($set);
```

and the output is:

```
[{"_id":"3","movie_name":"Despicable Me 2","movie_cinema_number":"CINEMA     1","movie_length":"1hr. 40mins.","movie_type":"GP","movie_schedules":"12:10 PM | 02:25 PM | 04:40 PM","movie_image_url":"http:\/\/i39.tinypic.com\/szizo4.jpg"},{"_id":"4","movie_name":"White House Down","movie_cinema_number":"CINEMA 2","movie_length":"2 hrs. 10 mins.","movie_type":"PG-13","movie_schedules":"12:30 PM | 03:20 PM | 06:10 PM","movie_image_url":"http:\/\/i39.tinypic.com\/vp9n9j.jpg"},{"_id":"5","movie_name":"My Lady Boss","movie_cinema_number":"CINEMA 3","movie_length":"1hr. 50 mins.","movie_type":"PG-13","movie_schedules":"01:00 PM | 03:30 PM | 06:00 PM","movie_image_url":"http:\/\/i44.tinypic.com\/2qlv08z.jpg"},{"_id":"6","movie_name":"Four Sisters And A Wedding","movie_cinema_number":"CINEMA 4","movie_length":"2 hrs. 5 mins. ","movie_type":"PG-13","movie_schedules":"12:30 PM | 03:10 PM | 05:50 PM","movie_image_url":"http:\/\/i44.tinypic.com\/9iv0d1.jpg"}]
```

what seems to be wrong that I do in here? URL is displayed as: http:\ /\ /i44.tinypic.com\ /9iv0d1.jpg where it should be http://i44.tinypic.com/9iv0d1.jpg

Comment: Arent these 2 urls you posted... identical?

Comment: you mean the fact that json_encode escaped the urls?

Comment: @DevZer0 yes I think so

Comment: @STTLCU I've edited my post, check it thanks.

Comment: json_encode adds a `\\` when it finds certain control chars. when you decode it the `\\` will be gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The JSON format is often used for serializing and transmitting structured data over a network connection. It is used primarily to transmit data between a server and web application, serving as an alternative to XML.

If you create an **API** that should be:

```
$array = array("title" => "TEST", "username" => "test"); // Creating a array
echo json_encode($array); // Printing json
```

Client want to request and get response:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/test/films.json'); // Your url
$array = json_decode($json); // Your first array its here!
```

**More:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
**Warning:** You can't edit or tidy your json response! It is good!

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not exists, actually.

What you're doing wrong is that you're using a piece of your JSON string without decoding it beforehand. Just use `json_decode(..)` if you're within PHP or the equivalent javascript function to decode JSON.

Once you did that, you'll have an object / an array which contains the data in the correct form.

Comment: @neknekmouh inside whichever script is listening for the echoed string. I don't know where you're sending this JSON, how can I answer you?

Comment: actually, I' going to lazy load this to my listview in an android app

Comment: @neknekmouh Then I presume you've some sort of AsyncTask doing the job. I'd decode this JSON inside the callback method located in your activity, but this is another problem altogether, you should write another question.

Comment: Okay so, the decoding must be done in my activity not here in my php script?

Comment: Think about it for a minute. You're ENCODING the results here in your PHP script. WHY ON EARTH would you also DECODE the string you just encoded in THIS PHP SCRIPT? Connect the dots :P